# Wing suit plus gas vs parachute?

Tags: science-based, sports

Would it be practical to use a "squirrel suit" and sacs of buoyant gas for deceleration from a free fall as opposed to a parachute? Furthermore, once the sacs have been inflated, could the person in the suit gain altitude? In this world, flitting from platform to platform is a form of sport.

Comment: Squirrel suits only give you control if you're going fast enough.  At speeds where sacs of buoyant gas are valid, squirrel suits are not very effective.  Did you have something in mind to make the squirrel suits more effective than my intuition suggests they will be?

Comment: If squirrel suits don't work, you could always use a tanooki suit.

Comment: @CortAmmon Ok, so what if, instead of helium sacs, there are vacuum sacs? If I'm right, gas sacs only float if they displace more air by weight than they weigh, right? So a vacuum sac would be like the ultimate lighter-than-air? I could science away any material needs.

Comment: What matters for boyancy is the *difference* in density. No matter how light your lifting gas you can't get more boyancy than the weight of the air you displace. Helium is already so much lighter than air that there isn't really much to be gained from lighter options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about a human then there actually isn't a whole lot of difference.

A similar question was asked to [xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/62/).

[image]

It ends up not all that different because the size of the gas bag required to lift a human is just about as big as a parachute. So, you could do this, but it would just make it much harder to steer and land where you want.

Another relevant [xkcd](https://what-if.xkcd.com/30/) eventually discusses what's required for a human to fly in an atmosphere by wearing wings.

[image]

The idea is explored in Lockstep by Karl Schroeder where humans fly in the upper atmosphere of a gas giant (with space suits).

I also recall this being discussed in a different science fiction book I read once where a kind of space elevator had buildings you could stop at on the way up. One of those buildings was high enough that the gravity was low enough for flight in the sea-level pressurized building. But I can't recall the name of that book.

Comment: Honestly, the first What-If you link to is pretty much the perfect answer to this question. Good job, Randall Munroe.

Comment: @KSmarts I think he has one of the best jobs in existence. At least, it appears that way from the outside.

Comment: It doesn't appear that way when he makes comics [like](http://xkcd.com/931/) [these](http://xkcd.com/1048/).

Comment: @KSmarts That's life, it's independent of the job. Notice money or work aren't on the radar before or after.

Comment: Fine. But the alt text on [this one](http://xkcd.com/745/) suggests that it is not as easy as you might think.

Comment: @KSmarts Yeah... I'm still not seeing how that's related to the job, people can have trouble with dyslexia everywhere in the modern world... But further discussion is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that something more parachute-like would work better than blowing up a bag of gas.

My recommendation would be a flying squirrel suit that lets them glide but can fold out to act like a parachute when they want to slow down, turning from a 'wing' to a 'break'.  With some good tech it could go back and forth, then you wouldn't need a supply of air for the balloons or the time to inflate/deflate them.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could get lift from a gas sac is if it was a light element like helium or very hot, making it less dense than ordinary air. Both would require a large volume, and then you've got a hot air balloon, not a suit. Combining a smaller volume with a suit designed for air resistance is an interesting idea, but I don't have the knowledge to know how well it would work. Essentially, you have a spectrum from a parachute with huge surface area at one end to a hot air/helium balloon with a huge volume at the other, so I would think that some form of less surface area than a parachute and less volume than a balloon would work. The question is how much less you could get away with.

Also, you mention inflation, implying they aren't inflated to begin with. That complicates things, and probably rules out helium, since where would it come from? Capturing regular air during the fall is possible, but then you need to heat it (and avoid burning your skydiver). Perhaps some chemical lining the empty sacs could trigger a thermal reaction as they fill up, which needs to be replaced every time. This would also prevent long flights or floating off too high, as the heat would run out and you would lose buoyancy.

Last, if your world doesn't need to be too Earth-like, there are factors that would make this more effective. High winds could provide lift to the squirrel suit portion. Lower gravity makes for less force to be fought against in general. A heavier atmosphere would make the air resistance of the squirrel suit work better, plus if you have pre-inflated sacs of a light gas, it would be more effective if the normal air is heavier. Last, and probably least, a colder environment to begin with could make the hot air solution more effective, but I'm not sure how much colder it would need to be to make a significant difference, plus you then need to generate more heat.

Oh, and this whole thing brought to mind the short novel Windhaven by Lisa Tuttle and George R. R. Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a engineer but if you had a squirrel suit that reduced the weight of a person wouldn't that reduce the stall speed and speed required for flight? Therefore making it possible to have a more controlled flight. If you used a gas that was already lighter than air you could use body heat to heat the gas, giving it more lift.

Larger sacks could be used on non control surfaces to give more lift. For the control surfaces between arms and legs you could use a mat effect with lots of thin gas sacks to retain flexibility whilst still having a minimal lift capability. This would not allow a person to fly but would reduce the speed required to glide. Or am I wrong?